# Possibility of indexing decision variables with 2 indices using a set of tuples in Pyomo

Tags: variables, constraints, modeling, pyomo

I am currently attempting to solve a network problem that is not fully connected.Thus,I have attempted to do some preprocessing of data so as to form a set of tuples, e.g. {(a,b , (c,e)}..., i.e. from a to b, from c to e.

I am able to declare binary decision variables with keys such as (a,b), (c,e), via using the set of tuples for indexing.

However, when I tried to use rules to declare constraints, with decision variables such as x[i][j], errors are thrown stating that (a,b) is an invalid index.

Hence, I would like to ask if tuples can be used as indices for decision variables.

If not, is there a way to only declare the only decision variables that are needed, rather than declaring all, and then setting those unneeded to 0.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the site.

You certainly CAN index variables with tuples of arbitrary dimensionality.  The code I have below shows an example of indexing `bad_X` with a tuple of nodes.  This makes sense when you have a variable that has a logical representation for all combinations of your indices or you control the indices somehow with smart set notation or you risk a whole bunch of nonsense variables as you can see in my example below with `bad_X` in the printout.

For your network, I would suggest just making a set of ARCS that are the valid combination of the NODES.  This set would just contain the tuples of the valid connections.  Note in my example below, the set of NODES could be blown away as it is not needed.  You could just create ARCS directly.  Sometimes it is handy to have both if you have some node-based data like supply/demand.

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

mdl = pyo.ConcreteModel()

arc_data = {    ('a', 'b'): 10,
                ('c', 'd'): 5,
                ('e', 'j'): 44,
                ('a', 'j'): 2,
                ('j', 'e'): 12}

# collapse the nodes into a set from the keys of the arc data
node_set = set()
for k in arc_data.keys():
    node_set.update(*k)


# Sets
mdl.NODES = pyo.Set(initialize=node_set)
mdl.ARCS = pyo.Set(within=mdl.NODES * mdl.NODES, initialize=arc_data.keys())

# Params
mdl.cost = pyo.Param(mdl.NODES, mdl.NODES, initialize=arc_data)

# Selection Variable:  poor choice...
mdl.bad_X = pyo.Var(mdl.NODES, mdl.NODES, domain=pyo.Binary)

# some examples of using this "bad X"
print('printing just to show how to access...this will produce a None')
print(mdl.bad_X['a', 'e'].value)
print(mdl.bad_X[('c', 'd')].value)    # also valid

# Better selection variable
mdl.X = pyo.Var(mdl.ARCS, domain=pyo.Binary)

# toy constraint...ensure at least 3 are selected
mdl.c1 = pyo.Constraint(expr=sum(mdl.X[arc] for arc in mdl.ARCS) >= 3)

# Objective:  Minimize cost of 3 selected arcs
mdl.OBJ = pyo.Objective(expr=sum(mdl.X[arc] * mdl.cost[arc] for arc in mdl.ARCS))

# to show the difference between the choices of variables
mdl.pprint()

# solve and show results
solver = pyo.SolverFactory('cbc')
results = solver.solve(mdl)
for arc in mdl.ARCS:
    print(arc, mdl.X[arc].value)
```

#### Output:

```
printing just to show how to access...this will produce a None
None
None
5 Set Declarations
    ARCS : Dim=0, Dimen=2, Size=5, Domain=ARCS_domain, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
        [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'j'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'j'), ('j', 'e')]
    ARCS_domain : Dim=0, Dimen=2, Size=36, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
        Virtual
    NODES : Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=6, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
        ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'j']
    bad_X_index : Dim=0, Dimen=2, Size=36, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
        Virtual
    cost_index : Dim=0, Dimen=2, Size=36, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
        Virtual

1 Param Declarations
    cost : Size=5, Index=cost_index, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
        Key        : Value
        ('a', 'b') :    10
        ('a', 'j') :     2
        ('c', 'd') :     5
        ('e', 'j') :    44
        ('j', 'e') :    12

2 Var Declarations
    X : Size=5, Index=ARCS
        Key        : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        ('a', 'b') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('a', 'j') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('c', 'd') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('e', 'j') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('j', 'e') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
    bad_X : Size=36, Index=bad_X_index
        Key        : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        ('a', 'a') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('a', 'b') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('a', 'c') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('a', 'd') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('a', 'e') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('a', 'j') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('b', 'a') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('b', 'b') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('b', 'c') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('b', 'd') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('b', 'e') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('b', 'j') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('c', 'a') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('c', 'b') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('c', 'c') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('c', 'd') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('c', 'e') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('c', 'j') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('d', 'a') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('d', 'b') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('d', 'c') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('d', 'd') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('d', 'e') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('d', 'j') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('e', 'a') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('e', 'b') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('e', 'c') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('e', 'd') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('e', 'e') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('e', 'j') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('j', 'a') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('j', 'b') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('j', 'c') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('j', 'd') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('j', 'e') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('j', 'j') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary

1 Objective Declarations
    OBJ : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Active : Sense    : Expression
        None :   True : minimize : 10*X[a,b] + 5*X[c,d] + 44*X[e,j] + 2*X[a,j] + 12*X[j,e]

1 Constraint Declarations
    c1 : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Lower : Body                                       : Upper : Active
        None :   3.0 : X[a,b] + X[c,d] + X[e,j] + X[a,j] + X[j,e] :  +Inf :   True

10 Declarations: NODES ARCS_domain ARCS cost_index cost bad_X_index bad_X X c1 OBJ
('a', 'b') 1.0
('c', 'd') 1.0
('e', 'j') 0.0
('a', 'j') 1.0
('j', 'e') 0.0
[Finished in 4.3s]
```

Comment: Dear Jeff, thank you for your reply. i think i managed to get to the stage of displaying only the binary variables which are needed. However, I was unable to index the constraints for two indices separately. E.g def mock_rule(model, i,j). I thought that pyomo would be able to recognize each index within the tuple separately,so that I could do stuff like create a constraint within two nested loops while iterating on each index separately. Thus, may I ask if you have a way to work around this especially when using rules to create constraints. Thanks!

Comment: @Mike Yes...  completely possible.  I'll post a second toy example as another answer to this question showing that type of indexing.  I don't want to muddy up the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Second answer to get at your second point about indexing in constraints...

This shows some variations of the concept you asked about.  Note that because I built params for every possible combination of city-year, that I needed to supply a default value for the ones that were not in my sparse data.

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

mdl = pyo.ConcreteModel()

demand_data = { ('LA', 1999):       500,
                ('LA', 2001):       700,
                ('NY', 2001):       600,
                ('Pheonix', 2000):  300,
                ('Pheonix', 2001):  400 }

my_favorites = {'LA'}  # a subset for example use

# Sets
mdl.CITIES = pyo.Set(initialize= {k[0] for k in demand_data.keys()})
mdl.YEARS =  pyo.Set(initialize= {k[1] for k in demand_data.keys()})

# Params
mdl.demand = pyo.Param(mdl.CITIES, mdl.YEARS, initialize=demand_data, default=0)
mdl.cost =   pyo.Param(mdl.YEARS, initialize={1999: 5, 2000: 10, 2001: 15}, default=0)

# Variable for supply
mdl.supply = pyo.Var(mdl.CITIES, mdl.YEARS, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)

#### Constraints ####

#ensure 1/2 of demand in each city-year pair
def half_demand(self, city, year):   
    return mdl.supply[city, year] >= 0.5 * mdl.demand[city, year]
mdl.c1 = pyo.Constraint(mdl.CITIES, mdl.YEARS, rule=half_demand)

# ensure favorite cities get all demand every year
def all_demand(self, city, year):
    return mdl.supply[city, year] >= mdl.demand[city, year]
mdl.c2 = pyo.Constraint(my_favorites, mdl.YEARS, rule=all_demand)

# ensure all demand is eventually met over all years
def eventually_met(self, city):
    return  sum(mdl.supply[city, year] for year in mdl.YEARS) >= \
            sum(mdl.demand[city, year] for year in mdl.YEARS)
mdl.c3 = pyo.Constraint(mdl.CITIES, rule=eventually_met)

#### OBJECTIVE ####
def objective(self):
    return sum(mdl.supply[city, year] * mdl.cost[year]
                for year in mdl.YEARS
                for city in mdl.CITIES)
mdl.OBJ = pyo.Objective(rule=objective)


# solve and show results
solver = pyo.SolverFactory('cbc')
results = solver.solve(mdl)
mdl.supply.display()
```

#### Output:

```
supply : Size=9, Index=supply_index
    Key               : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
         ('LA', 1999) :     0 : 500.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
         ('LA', 2000) :     0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
         ('LA', 2001) :     0 : 700.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
         ('NY', 1999) :     0 : 300.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
         ('NY', 2000) :     0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
         ('NY', 2001) :     0 : 300.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
    ('Pheonix', 1999) :     0 : 350.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
    ('Pheonix', 2000) :     0 : 150.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
    ('Pheonix', 2001) :     0 : 200.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
[Finished in 3.1s]
```

Comment: Dear Jeff, thank you for your reply again. It seems that the second example might be in unrelated to the first. I meant to ask how to form constraints by iterating within each of the indices within the tuples that were used to declare the decision variables in the first example. As in either iterate through every pair of just a subset. Thank you!

Comment: Well, I think the above example does that.  You'll have to post something else with a specific example of what you are trying to do and expected outcome if it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I think I wanted something like this for abstract model:  model.cons = ConstraintList()        
for i in model.nodes:
    for j in model.nodes:
        if [i,j] in tuples_list:
           model.cons.add("some expressions")
        else:
            Constraint.Skip  so as to obviate the need for setting parameters of (arcs) decision variables indexed by redundant tuples to zero, or even not defined them in the first place. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I managed to resolve the issue by first iterating to create a set of tuples that will be used for indexing and then invoke the constraint rule via checking all tuples against the set of tuples created for indexing.

Answer (score 0):

I think I manage to solve it, please refer to the example below

```
##First, create the set of tuples needed for filtering


#Op_Machine: set of (operation, machine) tuples created to avoid redundancy in decision variable declaration
Op_Machine=list()
for machine_id, op_proctime in Machine_Op_Time.items():
    for op in op_proctime.keys():
        print(Op_Machine)
        print((op,machine_id))
        Op_Machine.append((op,machine_id))
        print(Op_Machine)

##Next, invoke the rule using the if statement to filter across all possible indices accepting those combinations that are aligned with the tuples within the set
##Use Constraint.Skip to Skip creating constraints that do not belong to the set of tuples


def F1_rule(model,i,k):
    if (i,k) in Op_Machine:
        ##print(i,k)
        return model.Cmax>=model.completion_time[i,k]
    else:
        return Constraint.Skip            
            
#model.makespan= Constraint(model.op_set, model.mach_set, rule=Cmax_rule)
model.F1= Constraint(Operation_Set, Machine_Set, rule=F1_rule)
```

Note that the sets Operation_Set, Machine_Set function as the universal set as it comprises all combinations of operations and machines. Hence the statement model.F1= Constraint(Operation_Set, Machine_Set, rule=F1_rule) can be thought a for loop that iterates over all combinations while the if statement within the def function acts a filter to generate the needed constraints.